# Python Tkinter menubar command displays out of window

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I've been looking for a way to solve this. The menu command displays out of the main window, like it's anchored to the right of the 'Fichier' dropdown instead of to the left. There doesn't seem to be an option of this in the Menu args. Anyone knows how to make the menu stick to the inside of the window?

[Caption](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OhHTh.png)

```
class FenetrePrincipale(Tk):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        # ...

        self.menubar = Menu()
        self.menu_fichier = Menu(self.menubar, tearoff=0)
        self.menu_fichier.add_command(label="Ouvrir connexion...", command=self.ouvrir_connexion, accelerator="Ctrl+O")
        self.menubar.add_cascade(label="Fichier", menu=self.menu_fichier)
        self.config(menu=self.menubar)
```

Comment: Please include a [mcve] in your question.

Comment: Your code seems to be working as designed. If your window is narrower than the menu item, there's nothing to prevent the menu from exceeding the bounds of the window.